# how to get last modified/uploaded time of a file on amazon s3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have many files distributed on amazon s3 server and my local server. Now i want to clean the local server and move files to s3 server. I could do that [Amazon S3 PHP Class.](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) .

The problem is there might be files with same names. I have use the latest file. If it is on local server i can get file uploaded/modified time using php [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function. Now i want to a way to get file uploaded/modified time on s3 server. I googled and searched well before asking this question.  May be this is so simple but i cant get it.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a static file you can check the `Last-Modified` response header when you request it. It should say the last modification date of the file.

Comment: Yes this is what i want. Pretty simple. Thank you Shilpu

Comment: In fact S3 class i mentioned above returns the time as well. Thanks